# How can I look through a file and set an array for each time I found the same String? I am programming with bash code

Tags: arrays, string, bash, for-loop, grep

I am a beginner in bash code.
I am trying to set an array that contains different values that can be found in a file. The values I would like to add to the array are Strings that follow specific words. For example;
Lets say the file is

```
Subcase 201 
Node 101 
"Much more text here" 
Subcase 202 
Node 501
"Again more text here"
Subcase 301 Node 804
.......
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
Subcase="201" "202" "301"; Node="101" "501" "804".
```

Can someone help me please? I am not sure if I need to use a "for loop". I hope I were clear enough

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code for you service, please share some code making a genuine effort to solve this problem and where you are stuck and we will be happy to help

Comment: this would be much easier to do in `awk`. Are you restricted to just using `bash`? If you can use `awk`, read thru the tutorials at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html and then post your best attempt at solving the problem. Be sure to include your current sample output and error msgs (as well as input and expected output, as you have done). Good luck.

Comment: Great start at providing the elements of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Now all you need is your code .. and if I might make a suggestion, show your intended output in the format that bash will display it, for example as shown by `declare -p arrayname`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `read` builtin.  You can use `read` in a `while` loop.  The following example reads from stdin (pipe the file to the script) but you can use `read -r -u <fd> var vals` to select from a different stream if you need.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r var vals
do
   eval P_${var}'+=($vals)' 2>/dev/null
done

for var in ${!P_@}
do
  eval echo '"${var#P_} = ${'$var'[@]}"'
done
```

The assignment line ignores stderr because `var` may contain invalid chars for a bash variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that neither "Subcase" or "Node" appear twice on a given line of the original file, and that they are always spelled with the same case (first letter capitalized), the following code would achieve what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

#assuming that a specific targeted string only appears once on a given line, and it is always written with same case (first letter capitalized). Cleaning data and storing all values on temporary files
grep -e 'Subcase' /folder/file > /tmp/subcase-holder && sed -i -e 's/^.*Subcase//' /tmp/subcase-holder && sed -i -e "s/^[ \t]*/\"/" /tmp/subcase-holder && sed -i -e 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' /tmp/subcase-holder && sed -i -e 's/\s.*$//' /tmp/subcase-holder && sed -i -e 's/$/\"/' /tmp/subcase-holder
grep -e 'Node' /folder/file > /tmp/node-holder && sed -i -e 's/^.*Node//' /tmp/node-holder && sed -i -e "s/^[ \t]*/\"/" /tmp/node-holder && sed -i -e 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' /tmp/node-holder && sed -i -e 's/\s.*$//' /tmp/node-holder && sed -i -e 's/$/\"/' /tmp/node-holder

#creating output file
cat /tmp/subcase-holder | tr '\n'  ' ' > /tmp/subcase-holder2 && sed -e 's/.$/; Node\=/' /tmp/subcase-holder2 > /tmp/partial-answer && sed -i -e 's/^/Subcase\=/' /tmp/partial-answer
cat /tmp/node-holder | tr '\n'  ' ' > /tmp/node-holder2 && sed -e 's/.$/\./' /tmp/node-holder2 > /tmp/partial-answer2
cat /tmp/partial-answer /tmp/partial-answer2 > /tmp/answer && echo >> /tmp/answer

exit 0
```

The result is stored on the file /tmp/answer. By the way, the code does not use arrays, but it delivers the output you want.